# Does Jira have a Lookback or Snapshot api?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

I'm developing a cycle time report in another tool and connecting to Jira via REST api. During my research, I couldn't find any api in Jira similar to Lookupback api in Rally. The Changelog in Jira doesn't give enough information. I need to get the amount of time spent on an particular state, or how long an artifact was blocked or how long it was in Ready State. Any thoughts on how I could get his information?

Thanks,
Leo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such API in Jira. The whole state is persisted as a current values and only information about the past is in the form of a changelog.

> I need to get the amount of time spent on an particular state

Then you will have to parse the changelog, find the moment when issue changed to the desired status and iterate further through changelogs to the moment when status changed to something else.

> or how long an artifact was blocked

Then you need to monitor changelogs for issue links, follow those links and find when those issues were resolved.

> how long it was in Ready State

Depending on what you mean by ready state, if you mean how long issue was resolved this can be taken from resolution date. If you mean for example for how long all issues in a particular version or component were resolved you could run a JQL search and sort by resolution date.

Other option to changelog parsing would be to register yourself for issue updated events and start collecting data you need, this however will only work from the moment of plugin/addon installation without data from the past.